# Why isn't hydrochloric acid typically made via the photochlorination of hydrogen?

Tags: photochemistry

I understand that in large quantities the reaction is explosive but couldn't the flow of gas just be regulated to control the reaction? It seems like producing hydrogen chloride like this then dissolving it would be a very straightforward way to make hydrochloric acid.

To clarify, when I say 'typically' I mean on an industrial scale.

Comment: From gaseous hydrogen and chlorine? You already put a reason why it doesn't make sense and that's like top of a iceberg. Chlorine is plain nasty, and hydrogen is also explosive with air. Something can be possible, but completely unreasonable... probably most things are. It doesn't matter if in theory all could work out, if something goes bad and everyone in building dies.

Comment: Wait, but at least some of HCl **is** actually produced this way.

Comment: Might it have to do with the *cost* of the raw materials??

Comment: @IvanNeretin as a byproduct of chlorine production from brine electrolysis I would think.

Comment: I suspect it's due to thermal runaway and reaction control. Using heat may give more control that photoinitiation. It would have to be done continuously rather than in batch.